# check does not appear in checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery to show and hide a div when the user clicks on the appropriate checkbox.  This works correctly, but for whatever reason the check never shows up in the box.  Any suggestions?

jfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/p4m8c/

HTML

```
<p id="contingent-check"><label for="no-contingent"><input type="checkbox" name="no-contingent" value="yes" id="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Do not want to add Contingent Beneficiary</label></p>

      <div id="contingent"><h2>Contingent Beneficiary</h2>
      <label for="contingent-name" class="label">Beneficiary Name:</label><br />
        <input name="contingent-name" type="textfield" id="name" class="name-field">
        <p class="or-select">Or select from the list below</p>
        <label for="contingent-potential" class="label">Potential Beneficiary:</label><br />
        <select name="contingent-potential" class="drop-down">
          <option value="estate">Estate</option>
        </select>
        <p></p>
        <label for="contingent-relationship" class="label">Relationship:</label><br />
        <select name="contingent-relationship" class="drop-down">
          <option value="estate">Estate</option>
        </select>
        <p></p>
      </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#contingent-check').toggle(
    function(){
    $('#contingent input').attr('disabled' , true)
                          .css('backgroundColor', '#FCFCFC');
    $('#contingent select').attr('disabled' , true)
                          .css('color', '#BEBEBE')
                          .css('backgroundColor', '#FCFCFC');
    $('#contingent label').css('color', '#AEAEAE');
    $('#contingent .or-select').css('color', '#B2B2B2');
    $('#contingent h2').css('color', '#CACACA');
    },
    function(){
        $('#contingent input').attr('disabled' , false)
                          .css('backgroundColor', '');
    $('#contingent select').attr('disabled' , false)
                          .css('color', '')
                          .css('backgroundColor', '');
    $('#contingent label').css('color', '');
    $('#contingent .or-select').css('color', '');
    $('#contingent h2').css('color', '');
    });
```

Comment: @apsillers because the checkbox is a child, not a parent, element, and events propagate up the DOM, not down. In this case the click never makes it to the checkbox because the checkbox is disabled in the toggle callback.

Comment: @apsillers , thanks for noticing that...however i just added "checkbox-hide-div" to the id of the input and changed the first line of the jQuery from '#contingent-check' to "checkbox-hide-div" and the check box still won't show.

Comment: @MattBall - I thought that since the checkbox is sitting outside of the div it wouldn't disable the actual check.  I mean, the box is still clickable, so I am confused as to why this isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bind to the toggle on the p.  Bind to the change on the checkbox:

I changed the HTML to:

```
<p id="contingent-check"><input type="checkbox" name="no-contingent" value="yes" id="no-contingent" /><label for="no-contingent">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Do not want to add Contingent Beneficiary</label></p>
```

Then the script to:

```
$('#no-contingent').change(
function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
        $('#contingent input').attr('disabled', true).css('backgroundColor', '#FCFCFC');
        $('#contingent select').attr('disabled', true).css('color', '#BEBEBE').css('backgroundColor', '#FCFCFC');
        $('#contingent label').css('color', '#AEAEAE');
        $('#contingent .or-select').css('color', '#B2B2B2');
        $('#contingent h2').css('color', '#CACACA');
    }
    else {
        $('#contingent input').attr('disabled', false).css('backgroundColor', '');
        $('#contingent select').attr('disabled', false).css('color', '').css('backgroundColor', '');
        $('#contingent label').css('color', '');
        $('#contingent .or-select').css('color', '');
        $('#contingent h2').css('color', '');
    }
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p4m8c/12/

Answer (score 0):

You have placed your checkbox inside a paragraph, and the click event is happening on the paragraph, not the checkbox.

The best thing would probably be to move the checkbox out of the paragraph, or you can toggle the checkbox in your `toggle()` function:

```
$('#contingent-check').toggle(
    function() {
        var checkbox = $('[name="no-contingent"]')[0];
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
        $('#contingent input').attr('disabled', true).css('backgroundColor', '#FCFCFC');
        $('#contingent select').attr('disabled', true).css('color', '#BEBEBE').css('backgroundColor', '#FCFCFC');
        $('#contingent label').css('color', '#AEAEAE');
        $('#contingent .or-select').css('color', '#B2B2B2');
        $('#contingent h2').css('color', '#CACACA');
    }, function() {
        var checkbox = $('[name="no-contingent"]')[0];
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
        $('#contingent input').attr('disabled', false).css('backgroundColor', '');
        $('#contingent select').attr('disabled', false).css('color', '').css('backgroundColor', '');
        $('#contingent label').css('color', '');
        $('#contingent .or-select').css('color', '');
        $('#contingent h2').css('color', '');
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p4m8c/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Bind change event to your check box.. and use ternary to shorten your code.  I also assume you are using jQuery 1.7 since thats how you had your jsfiddle set up.  You should be using `prop` instead of `attr` to set your `disabled` property

```
$('#no-contingent').change(function() {
    var $checked = this.checked; // <-- store boolean - if checkbox is checked -  to use for ternary and set disabled property
    // added select in here since select gets same treatment for disabled and background color
    $('#contingent input,#contingent select').prop('disabled', $checked).css('backgroundColor', $checked ? '#FCFCFC' : '');
    $('#contingent select').css('color', $checked ? '#BEBEBE' : '');
    $('#contingent label').css('color', $checked ? '#AEAEAE' : '');
    $('#contingent .or-select').css('color', $checked ? '#B2B2B2' : '');
    $('#contingent h2').css('color', $checked ? '#CACACA' : '');
});
```

and removed the `p` tag from html.  added `id` to input

```
<input id='no-contingent' type="checkbox" name="no-contingent" value="yes"
id="" />
<label for="no-contingent">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Do not want to add Contingent Beneficiary</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/p4m8c/19/

Answer (score 0):

This works, I binded it to the checkbox on click http://jsfiddle.net/p4m8c/17/

```
$('#contingent-check input[type=checkbox]').click(
function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#contingent input').attr('disabled' , true).css('backgroundColor', '#FCFCFC');
        $('#contingent select').attr('disabled' , true).css('color', '#BEBEBE').css('backgroundColor', '#FCFCFC');
        $('#contingent label').css('color', '#AEAEAE');
        $('#contingent .or-select').css('color', '#B2B2B2');
        $('#contingent h2').css('color', '#CACACA');
    }
    else {
        $('#contingent input').attr('disabled' , false).css('backgroundColor', '');
        $('#contingent select').attr('disabled' , false).css('color', '').css('backgroundColor', '');
        $('#contingent label').css('color', '');
        $('#contingent .or-select').css('color', '');
        $('#contingent h2').css('color', '');
    }
}
```

);​